How to calculate the KL divergence between two multivariate complex Gaussian distributions?
I am reading a paper "Complex-Valued Variational Autoencoder: A Novel Deep Generative Model for Direct Representation of Complex Spectra"
In this paper, the author calculate the KL divergence between two multivariate complex gaussian distributions
$q(h|z)$ are diagonal. $p(h)$ is $N(0,I,0)$" />

the complex gaussian distributions are special. the covariance matrix and pseudo cov matrix of q(h|z) are diagonal. p(h) is N(0,I,0)

I wonder if p(h) is not N(0,I,0), instead, p(h) is also a complex gaussian distribution such that the covariance matrix and pseudo cov matrix of p(h) are diagonal, what is KL(q(h|z)||p(h))???
is there any book or paper to calculate the KL divergence between two multivariate gaussian distributions? i can not find relevant information online.
someone has idea about this question? thank you!!!!!

Because a Complex Gaussian distribution is a Gaussian distribution (in the real and imaginary variables), just apply the usual formula.  You can find various solutions by searching our site.
